# hosting my backend and frontend on firebase

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, deployment

i have my test project built with react js ( frontend ) and node js ( backend ) with these respective schema.

-frontend ( folder)

---- react js

-backend ( folder)

---- express js

locally it works perfectly but now I would like to publish it on firabase hosting
how you do it ?
if I had to publish only the frontend I would already know how to do it because I have already done other tests but with two folders how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not allow direct hosting of a node application. What you need to do is host your backend as a firebase function. See [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#use_a_web_framework) for this.